# what's wrong with my recursive binary search algorithm?

Tags: c++, recursion, search, binary-search

I have tried to search a data in a structure like 1D array, but it always tell me that the target data has not been found, although I have make the algorithm exactly as it is. now I am  totally confused

the below is how I define function

```
int RecBinarySearch (int a[], int low, int high, int key) {

    int mid{ };

    if (high >= low  ) {
        mid =  low + (high-low)/2;

        if (key == a[mid]) return mid;
        if (key > a[mid]) RecBinarySearch(a, mid + 1, high, key);
        if (key < a[mid]) RecBinarySearch(a, low, mid - 1, key);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

and here you see how I define my array

```
int n{};
int* a = new int [n] {};
```

Comment: Note: remove the `c` tag, your code is C++, not C. Different languages, different solutions.

Comment: @LucaPolito  `int a[n];` in C :). `RecBinarySearch` is C compatible (except this `mid{}`), `c` tag should stay

Comment: @tstanisl I get your point. But in general, a C solution may not be ideal (not leveraging all the features of C++), and a C++ solution may be wrong in C.

Comment: @tstanisl `int* a = new int [n] {};` is not C. `int mid{ };` is not C. But it's written like you would write C code.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and show a [MRE].

Comment: It's a minor thing, but please note that there's no reason not to scope `mid` entirely within the first conditional branch. It isn't used elsewhere in your function.

Comment: As written, your function returns -1.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Except when the `key` happens to be at `mid`.

Comment: @jxh: oooops, yes.

Comment: There was a point to the discussion, but it was rendered moot by the removal of the C tag.

Answer (score 4):

When you recursively call a function that is supposed to return something, you need to return what the recursive call would return.

```
    if (key > a[mid]) return RecBinarySearch(a, mid + 1, high, key);
    if (key < a[mid]) return RecBinarySearch(a, low, mid - 1, key);
```

---

> Okay, don't take that literally. It is true for most divide and conquer style recursive algorithms and greedy style algorithms, where the recursive call is designed to find the answer. Then, that answer has to be propagated up. There are other cases where the recursive call is just finding a portion of the solution. In those cases, the result needs to be incorporated into the final answer.
>
> The point is, however, that you are ignoring the returned result of the recursive call, which is triggering a bug where you will return `-1` instead of the answer found by the call.

---

Note that C++ includes [`binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) (and C includes [`bsearch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch)).

Comment: Thank you so much bro, so useful and that's a real point I missed really 10 Q so much

Comment: @SanaAllahKheiri Consider taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

int RecBinarySearch(int a[], int low, int high, int key)
{
  if (high >= low)
  {
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

    if (key == a[mid])
      return mid;
    if (key > a[mid])
      return RecBinarySearch(a, mid + 1, high, key);  // you forgot the return statement
    if (key < a[mid])
      return RecBinarySearch(a, low, mid - 1, key);   // you forgot the return statement
  }

  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  int values[] = { 1,3,4,5,6,7 };   // must be sorted

  // check if we find each of the values contained in values
  for (auto v : values)
  {
    if (RecBinarySearch(values, 0, 7, v) == -1)
    {
      std::cout << v << " not found\n";
    }
  }

  int valuesnotcontained[] = {0,2,8,10};

  // check we don't find values not contained in values
  for (auto v : valuesnotcontained)
  {
    if (RecBinarySearch(values, 0, 7, v) != -1)
    {
      std::cout << v << " should not be found\n";
    }
  }
}
```

It includes some basic test code.

Comment: I have written that but my need is recursion

Comment: @SanaAllahKheiri but there __is__ recursion in the code in my answer... The difference is that in my code I use the return statement, but you don't.